# ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!

Tags: ros, turtlebot, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm Korean student. So i cannot speak English very well.
Thank you for your consideration.

I am setting Turtlebot on my netbook and my notebook (Network Connection)
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup

My netbook is TurtleBot laptop.
My notebook is Workstation.

I am able to ping each other.
One is 192.168.0.67 and another is 192.168.0.63

and i can see "echo $ROS_MASTER_URI" and "echo $ROS_HOSTNAME". "turtlebot start/running, process 16951" also.

but when i enter the command "rostopic list", i see "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!"

I don't know why..
because when i set "Network Setup" first time, there work correctly..
but after the reboot, i cannot do anything..

Please help me ~.~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30106/error:-unable-to-communicate-with-master!/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-03-20**:
could you post the output of "echo $ROS_MASTER_URI" and "echo $ROS_HOSTNAME"? Many times when I get this error, it's because of settings error

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-21**:
my notebook..   ROS_MASTER_URI == http://192.168.0.67:11311   and ROS_HOSTNAME == 192.168.0.63
and my netbook.. ROS_MASTER_URI == http://192.168.0.67:11311  and ROS_HOSTNAME == 192.168.0.67

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-21**:
IP of my notebook is 192.168.0.64  (turtlebot-workspace)
IP of my netbook is 192.168.0.67   (turtlebot-robot)

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-21**:
i think "roscore" is right..
but.. i cannot start turtlebot service..
when i enter the command "sudo service turtlebot start", i can see the message "rustlebot start/running, process 3326"
and i enter the command "rostopic list", i can see the message only "/rosout" and "/rosout_agg"
i don't know..

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-03-22**:
not sure if it's a typo, but in your comments, your turtlebot-workspace IP 192.168.0.64 does not match the notebook's ROS_HOSTNAME 192.168.0.63 so that could be why it's not working correctly

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-03-23**:
oh sorry. i was miss typing.. t.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not familiar with the turtlebot setup, but this typically means that you do not have a roscore running. Open a new shell, type "roscore" and try again...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3